# How do I get the Uri of an image from its returned position of a gridview

Tags: android

I currently have a gridview that returns an images position/id to a parent activity. I would also like to return or extract the images Uri to the parent activity and set it to a variable that can be parsed somewhere else in the parent activity. I've been looking for a bit but cant quite find a solution that fits what I'm attempting.

My gridview child activity that returns the position

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout);

    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

    // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    /**
     * On Click event for Single Gridview Item
     * */
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                int position, long id) {


            Intent data = new Intent(PicPicker2.this, PictureActivity.class);
            // passing array index
            data.putExtra("id", position);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

}

Where I currently catch the result in the parent activity

```
            else if (reqCode == 2) {


                // Selected image id
                int position = data.getExtras().getInt("id");
                ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
                ChosenImageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
              }
            }
        }
```

Where I want to parse the variable

```
        Uri attached_Uri = Uri.parse("SOME VARIABLE OF THE RETURNED URI");
```

I want to set Uri attached_Uri = Uri.parse() to the item that was clicked in the gridview. I'm just a weekend Android tinkerer trying to learn the concepts of the platform so explanations and examples go a long way for me and are greatly appreciated.

Added my imageadapter

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private Context mContext;


// Keep all Images in array
public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.pic_1, R.drawable.pic_2,
        R.drawable.pic_3, R.drawable.pic_4,
        R.drawable.pic_5, R.drawable.pic_6,
        R.drawable.pic_7, R.drawable.pic_8,
        R.drawable.pic_9, R.drawable.pic_10,
        R.drawable.pic_11, R.drawable.pic_12,
        R.drawable.pic_13, R.drawable.pic_14,
        R.drawable.pic_15
};

// Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c){
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
    return imageView;
}
```

}

Comment: what is your `ImageAdapter` looks like? I think it has something from which you can get Uri of Image.

Comment: Ok, so you need a Resource id of selected drawable?

Comment: Try this, `((ImageAdapter)parent).mThumbIds[position];` in `onItemClick()`.

Comment: Yep, I want to set the Uri attached_Uri I listed previously to the drawable that is selected from the gridview. I keep getting lost on which method would work best and where I should put it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using resources as images, so the uris are of the form `"android.resource://your.package.name/resource_id"`.  To be more specific, lets say you have the index of the image in a variable `position` (as you would in the `onClick` method), and you've got an instance of `ImageAdapter` in `mImageAdapter` (note that in your case you could just create a new copy of the adapter, but generally you'd want to use a common instance).  Then the following will get you your `Uri`

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.name/" + 
     mImageAdapter.getItem(position));
```

In the above code `"your.package.name"` is the name of the package as defined in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Comment: Hmm I'm trying to pass that into an mms (picture mail) intent, you may have solved my original problem however Im now getting a toast on the device stating  "Sorry you cannot add this picture to your message" your thoughts? Seems its another can of worms to sort.

Comment: Did some research, have to store the images in a location/file that the messenger can also access.